# include all directory files in class

Tags: php, class, include

I have a php file like this

```
class Config {

   public static $__routes = array(

       "Home"                    => "index.php",
       "Support"                 => "support.php",

   );

}

Config::__routes += (include 'config/example1.php');
Config::__routes += (include 'config/example2.php');
```

can I include a directory

for example:

```
include('include 'config/example1.php');
include('include 'config/example2.php');
```

will be something like:

```
include('config/*');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `glob` try:

```
foreach (glob('config/*.php') as $file)
    include( $file );
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will include all .php files in a given folder.

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/includes/folder')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        $path_parts = pathinfo($entry);
    if ($path_parts['extension'] == '.php') include $entry;
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

explanation:
opendir will open the given folder and return handle of folder.
while loop will loop through all files in that folder.

pathinfo will create an array include file information which one of then is extension of file.

Then we compare extension of found file to .php, if it was php file, we include it.
Then we close the handle of opened folder.